# How to flat Json file using Python?

Tags: python, json

I have the following input:
https://textuploader.com/dz3xo

This contains two orders.

The input can be converted into Json using:

```
print json.dumps(response2)
```

I want to manipulate this input to be shown as Json of like the following:

https://jsonblob.com/85f329dc-994c-11e8-8a91-931af4d591d9

The manipulation is simple:  Any Sub-Json is removed and join to the father Json.

I wrote following functions:

```
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + str(a) + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out


def generatejson2(response2):
    sample_object = pd.DataFrame(response2).to_dict()
    flat = {k: flatten_json(v) for k, v in sample_object.items()}
    return json.dumps(flat, sort_keys=True)


response2 = Func_Create_Data()
flat_json = generatejson2(response2)
```

However this is not my desired out put it. It gives:
[image]

It mix data from the two orders under the same index. The row numbers should never be in the index name.

I can't find the problem with my code. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flatten function should be working right, are you sure you're handing it the right information in the line

```
flat = {k: flatten_json(v) for k, v in sample_object.items()}
```

it looks a lot like the 'k' in that line is ['customer', 'shippingAddress', ...] rather than the expected ['0', '1']. My guess is you should have a

```
0_country_currency_id: 2
```

inside your shippingAddress?

Comment: nop.. The first line in my question is the source input you can see there is no such value in the shipping address.. the 0 and 1 comes from the row numbers...

Comment: I meant inside the shippingAddress {62} line in the pic close to the bottom of your post, not in the original. and yeah, that's where the 0 and 1 come from, but I think those and the highest-level keys in the dict are getting swapped somewhere.

Comment: The pic is the output of the code which is wrong. The desired output is: https://jsonblob.com/85f329dc-994c-11e8-8a91-931af4d591d9   where can they be swapped?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's most likely in the first two lines of generatejson2. One of those lines is probably not giving the result you think it should be. The flatten_json function works, using it on just the contents of one order I get https://jsonblob.com/de772af9-995d-11e8-8a91-f3b26d260dd6, which matches yours, so the only possibility is that it was handed data in a wrong format.

Comment: It think it's most likely 'pd.DataFrame(response2).to_dict()', you should take a look at what that's actually giving you.

Comment: Most likely this is the problem.. I set up this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704619/conversion-between-json-and-dataframe-using-python   to find out.. See if you can find the problem? I couldn't