# Conversion between Json and DataFrame using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
sample_object = pd.DataFrame(responsedata.json())['results'].to_dict()
func(sample_object)
```

Now,
I have another get call using function which does some manipulation over the data:

```
responsedata2 = get_data(url2)
```

I do know that:

`responsedata2`  is equivalent to `responsedata.json()['results']`

as if I do:

```
print responsedata2  
print responsedata.json()['results']
```

I will get the same output (If called with the same URL).

My question is how can I create `sample_object2` that will be equivalent to `sample_object1`  so I will be able to do: `func(sample_object2)`

Any idea how to make it works? It seems simply but the involvement of the `DataFrame` makes it hard.

**Edit**:

To explain better what I'm after.
I want to write a function that gets object like `responsedata2`   and return object like `sample_object`.

Comment: Can you provide some example data, and some more information on what `func()` and `getdata()` do? At present it's not very clear where your problem is.

Comment: @asongtoruin tried that before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692872/how-to-convert-response-from-request-get-to-dataframe it got people confuse.   Here I'm looking for something simpler... Just convert types.  Take `responsedata2`   and convert it to `sample_object`   When the information you know is that `responsedata2`    is the same as `responsedata.json()['results']`

Comment: Could you please give an example of the input data and the corresponding output you expect ?

Comment: @joaquin  responsedata  Is a {Response} <Response [200]> object   it gives: https://textuploader.com/dz3u0    sample_object is a dictionary as:  https://textuploader.com/dz3uj   This conversion is done by my code successfuly. responsedata2  is https://textuploader.com/dz3ux

Comment: @asongtoruin see above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell `pd.DataFrame(responsedata.json())['results'].to_dict()`

gives you `{0: (first data set), 1: (second data set)}`,

while `responsedata.json()['results']`

gives you a list of `[(first data set), (second data set)]`.

In order to turn the list into a dictionary like the first, use

```
sample_object = {i: data for i, data in enumerate(responsedata2)}
```

`enumerate` is a generator that takes an iterable such as ['a', 'b', 'c', ...] and returns tuples (0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), etc.

Comment: Are you referring to :     `temp = {i: data for i, data in enumerate(responsedata2 )}
    sample_object = pd.DataFrame(temp).to_dict()`   ?

Comment: No, just sample_object = {i: data for i, data in enumerate(responsedata2)} ought to give you the {0: (first data set), 1: (second data set)} dict that I think you want. Trying to pass that into DataFrame should fail anyway.

Comment: I used what I wrote and it worked. Then I removed the 2nd row and it worked either :) not sure what's going on I'm just glad it's working. If you can explain it that would be awesome

Comment: Huh, then again I don't have a lot of experience with pandas. I think what it's doing is just taking the dict, turning it into a DataFrame, then turning it right back into a dict. Sort of what happens if you write `int(str(2))`.